# Add a button to submit changes on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

im creating a new post instead of the older because here i can explain much better.

Im doing a little project in ASP.NET , currently using Visual Studio 2012. Its a web project.

I have to generate "cards" based on the info i get from an SQL database.

In the code behind of my page i have a while loop that creates as many "cards" as entries are on the database. In the cards i put a select tag with options, i want to be able to select one option and have a button that updates the info in the database with my selected option.

I've tried using runat server, adding a handler but the button never works, it does nothing. Here is the code in question. Take note that im generating the html code from the code behind, because its dynamically generated.

I think that the problem is that i generate the html from code-behind.
Here is the code, the " & & " are sql references, dont pay attention to them.

```
html = "<div class='col-lg-3'> <div class='panel panel-default'> <div class='panel-heading' style=' background-color: #dc381c; '>Nº: " & id_ticket.ToString & " - " & Urgente.ToString & " </div> <!-- /.panel-heading --> <div class='panel-body'> <div class='row'> <div class='col-lg-12 col-lg-12'> <div class='thumbnail' style='background-color:rgba(60, 88, 188, 0.15); border-color: red;'>  <div class='caption'> <h2>DIR: " & Calle_Numero.ToString & "</h2> <h4>ED: " & Nombre_Edificio.ToString & "</h4> <h4>TIPO: " & Tipo_Urgente.ToString & "</h4> <h4>TEL: " & Tel_Contacto.ToString & "</h4> <h5>DETALLE: " & Detalle_Problema.ToString & "</h5> <p style='text-align: center;'> <select id='testSelect' name='testSelect' runat='server'>  <option value='volver'>Volver</option> <option value='reparacion'>En Reparacion</option> <option value='solucionado'>Solucionado</option>  </select></p><input type='button'  runat='server' onclick='Responder_Ticket' name='" & id_ticket.ToString & "'  id='" & id_ticket.ToString & "'></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>"
```

Im new to asp.net, so maybe im not being very clear in all details. 
I read a lot of post to problems like this but nothing helped me.
tl;dr : the button for submiting the changes doesnt work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of generating this code. try using a ListView which has item templates & can be bound to a data source. that would be much more readable & you would get a good control over events.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat unclear, but I think you would be better off using a GridView control to populate your cards.  That way, you can use the RowCommand function to handle the event. You can set the DataSource of the GridView with your SQL DataSet/Table, and use code like the following to read where the user input took place:

```
Protected Sub dgChecks_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = dgChecks.Rows(index)
    Dim btnOK, btnNG As Button
    Dim i, iIssueID As Integer

    btnOK = dgChecks.Rows(index).Cells(3).Controls(0)
    btnNG = dgChecks.Rows(index).Cells(4).Controls(0)
    ....
End Sub
```